# Create std::pair<std::string, some_enum> via preprocessor

Tags: c++, c++14, preprocessor

I have a const static std::map and I want to fill it with the preprocessor. I want a mapping between my enumeration and string-names of the enum type. For example:

```
enum Color {
  RED,
  BLUE,
  GREEN
};

const static std::map<std::string, Color> = {
  {"RED", Color::RED},
  {"red", Color::RED},
  {"BLUE", Color::BLUE},
  {"blue", Color::BLUE},
  {"GREEN", Color::GREEN}
  {"green", Color::GREEN}
};
```

That is a simple example. I want to write something like:

```
enum Color {
  RED,
  BLUE,
  GREEN
};

const static std::map<std::string, Color> = {
  CREATE(RED),
  CREATE(BLUE),
  CREATE(GREEN)
};
```

I have lots of values in my enumeration and you see that it is a lot of work, even for a few values.
I thought about using some preprocessor magic but I don't know how to get it working. My first thought was:

```
#define(name) {"name", Color::name}
```

My second thought was:

```
#define(name) {"(name)", Color::(name)}
```

In the first case I get the string "name" as the key, in the second case I get the string "(name)" as the key and a compiler error because of my value. It would be great to get a solution for this problem, even if this would not include a lower-case version of the string. That would just be a small bonus.
Do you have any ideas how I could solve my problem?

edit: Thank's to @Gem Taylor. I have a solution for the first problem:

```
#define CREATE(name) {#name, Color::name}
```

If you have an idea how to create the version with the lowercase string, that would be great. So that:

```
CREATE(RED)
```

would create:

```
{"RED", Color::RED}, {"red", Color::RED}
```

Thank's

Comment: Look up the preprocessor stringising operator.

Comment: See the ["stringification" operator (`#`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace).

Comment: for this case, it seems a good case for a case-insensitive comparator for your map. Alternatively, instead of  `set`, call a method that generates and adds the lower case version, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special stringifier feature in macros #, and also token concatenation ## :

```
#define CREATE(name) {#name, Color::name}
```

See [the gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) - this is a standard feature of C.

Comment: To be clear, this isn't a gcc feature. It's a [standard feature](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace).

Comment: Thanks. That works perfect. Do you have a clue how a could also insert a lower case version of my string?

Comment: You have to call function for that (or similar).

Comment: Alternatively, if you used const char pointers and wrote your own map comparator that used stricmp then you could avoid doing the to-lower conversion.

Comment: @GemTaylor: No need to switch to const char pointer to customize the comparer.

Comment: Thought that there is maybe some compile-time solution. But yes, there are some workarounds i could use.

Comment: @Jarod42 - indeed, you can do case ignore compares on std::string, but you still have to resort to "C" methods, and .c_str(). If the input strings are compile-time C constants, I would use them directly and cut out the "middle man". Note that stricmp is generally slower than strcmp. You could also consider an unordered_map, but then need to write a case-ignoring hash function.

Comment: @Schorsch If you only want to accept a capitalised input, then the custom mapping or hash function removes the capitalisation from the check and you don't need to duplicate them. If you actually want to offer these names in some UI feature, you wouldn't want to duplicate them anyway.

Comment: @GemTaylor it was a 'feature' i don't need anymore. I need it for mapping between some input identifiers and my own enumeration-type. In my case it is clearer to only accept one spelling for identifiers.